# How do I convert decimal encoded hex to ascii in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

What I have is a string of integer values that represent Letters and Numbers in pairs.  I would like to use SQL to do the conversion from `'12371 12595 8224'` to `'S031  '`

I've gotten to here...

```sql
CAST(CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(DataString,1,CHARINDEX(CHAR(9),DataString)-1) as bigint) AS VARBINARY(2)) AS VARCHAR(2))  but that gets me '0S'
```

Note: The `CHAR(9)` is because the integers are tab delimited.

Comment: How does `'12371 12595 8224'` (which is also not a `decimal` as your title says, or a `bigint` as your code suggests) translate to `'S032'`?

Comment: 12371 is 0x3053  so is the integer representation of the hex value.  So that is a hex pair, encoded as an integer.  0x30 is the hex representation of the character 0. 0x53 is the hex representation of the character S.  Just as shown in my code snippet.

Comment: That doesn't explain how `'12371 12595 8224' = 'S032'`. Nor tells us what your original source value is.

Comment: So your byte order is reversed as 12371 is 0S as you noted.  I make your expected value `S031` not S032.

Comment: OOPS!~!!!  I will correct in my initial question.  Thanks Stu.

Comment: Can you explain how come you want '12371 12595 8224' to 'S031  ' ? Any logic behind that?

Comment: Yes.  I'm getting data from a device that outputs character pairs that way.  So in the table there is a field that contains a string that has 268, tab delimited, integers.  Each integer represents a pair of characters.  I just need a simple way to convert from one form to the other.

Answer (score 0):

So here's one way you can get your desired output. Because you're using 2012 there are some useful functions for splitting and aggregating strings that are not available to you.

This makes use of a tally/numbers table - simulated here with `values()` - but you would have a permanent table of numbers to use.

This splits the string into rows, and then simply extracts the high/low bytes and uses `for xml path` to aggregate back into a string.

See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=fb7d06fdd060d6f140be3f89206d0cd6)

```
declare @v varchar(50)='12371 12595 8224', @delimiter varchar(1)=' ';

with v as (
    select Convert(int,Substring(@delimiter+@v+@delimiter, n.n+1, CharIndex(@delimiter, @delimiter+@v+@delimiter, n.n+1)-n.n-1)) as v
    from 
    /* replace this with tally / numbers table */
    (select * from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20))n(n))n
    where n.n <= len(@delimiter+@v+@delimiter)-1
        and substring(@delimiter+@v+@delimiter, n.n, 1) = @delimiter
)

select Concat(Char(v & 0x00ff), char(v/256))
from v
for xml path(''), type
```

Answer (score 0):

I dug a bit deeper into the datastring and found that I only had to decode the first 6 integers.  So I went ugly.  Considering how far I was already, the missing piece was the Reverse function.

```
  REVERSE(CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(DataString,1,5) as bigint) AS VARBINARY(2)))+
  REVERSE(CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(DataString,7,5) as bigint) AS VARBINARY(2)))+
  REVERSE(CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(DataString,13,4) as bigint) AS VARBINARY(2)))+
  REVERSE(CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(DataString,18,4) as bigint) AS VARBINARY(2)))+
  REVERSE(CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(DataString,23,5) as bigint) AS VARBINARY(2)))+
  REVERSE(CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(DataString,29,5) as bigint) AS VARBINARY(2))) AS [Output Code]
```

Had I needed to go through all of the integers in the string, a While loop would have worked fine.